How to make checkout of a repository using git-lfs fail if git-lfs isn't installed
It seems that if you try to clone & checkout a git repository which makes use of git-lfs, while the current machine doesn't have git-lfs installed, it simply 'works' without any errors or warnings, but 'does the wrong thing' (by checking out 'pointer' files instead of what they point to, if they're being managed by git-lfs)
Is there an option you can pass to git clone and/or git checkout which will cause them to fail in this situation, to short-circuit any debugging later on due to the 'large files' being mangled?

Maybe just git lfs && git clone and git lfs && git checkout. git lfs is not a built-in git command. I don't think git clone and git checkout would implement an option to check if it exists.

Git by itself knows nothing about LFS; LFS pointers are just files for Git and there is no an option to fail if Git-LFS is not available. Git-LFS support is implemented using filters in global ~/.gitconfig or local .git/config. If you want Git to fail without LFS you need to configure some filters instead that fail.

It seems like having an option that would cause an error if any files that were checked out were configured to have a filter (via .gitattributes) and no such filter was configured locally would be useful?

@Bwmat Gonna implement it and send a patch to Git developers? Or at least ask said Git developers?

@phd - I was explaining my reasoning in believing such an option would exist. It's possible I'll eventually gain the motivation to attempt to make it so in the future, but I wouldn't depend on it if I were you.
